# Default width with Srcset on Chrome/FF

Tags: html, dom, srcset

I'm implementing a page where we want to use srcset. The problem is that i want the image to render with default size, without setting its width.

It seems this is not possible on Chrome/FF. Surprisingly IE11 is showing this as I  thought it should..

Take a look at this example:

```
<img src="http://www.komplett.no/img/p/200/F359034.jpg" srcset="http://www.komplett.no/img/p/200/F359034.jpg 200w,
                     http://www.komplett.no/img/p/200/F359034.jpg 200w ">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/goa3xu5f/

Here you see that the image will take as much width as possible, even though the image is much smaller.

If you don't set srcset it load with its initial size:

```
<img src="http://www.komplett.no/img/p/200/F359034.jpg">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g7j6fgd2/

I dont know if this is a bug or not, but does anyone know how I can use srcset and still show the image as it's original size and not with the browser scaling it up?

Answer (score 0):

This works fine check this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/v8czg13m/)**

```
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c6/Russell_Falls_2.jpg" srcset="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c6/Russell_Falls_2.jpg 1x, http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c6/Russell_Falls_2.jpg 2x">
```

Comment: This is not the same. You use resolution based `srcset` while @Numm3n used viewport based `srcset`.

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood what the size specification meant, and now I understand why it is behaving like this. I recommend to read this 
https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-youre-just-changing-resolutions-use-srcset/

Answer (score 0):

This is because you need to set the `sizes` attribute to tell the browser at which size it should be shown.

`sizes` is now a mandatory attribute, but if it is not present, the default value is `100vw`, which means the full width of the viewport.